# How to reduce Audio and Video file size while downloading from server in Android app?

Tags: java, android

I need to either play or download audio/video files hosted on a server.
While downloading, I need the file to be downloaded in compressed size.
How to achieve that?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Audio and video file formats typically employ compression already, so you can't generally do any further compression on them.  Thus the good news is that you have nothing to do - your current downloading mechanism already includes compression!